Closure operators and uniqueness of the size of basis
Let $M$ be a set. A closure operator is a function $cl:\mathcal{P}(M)\to\mathcal{P}(M)$
such that
$\bullet$ $A\subseteq cl(A)$
$\bullet$ if $A\subseteq B$ then $cl(A)\subseteq cl(B)$
$\bullet$ $cl(cl(A))=cl(A)$
Besides we say that
$\bullet$ $A\subseteq M$ is $\textit{independent}$ if for all $a\in A$ we have that $a\notin cl(A\cup\{a\})$.
$\bullet$ $A\subseteq M$ is a $\textit{basis}$ if is independent and $cl(A)=M$.
$\bullet$ $cl$ has the $\textit{exchange property}$ if for all $a,b\in M$ is true that $a\in cl(A\cup\{b\})\setminus cl(A)$ then $b\in cl(A\cup\{a\})$.
I want to prove that if $A$ and $B$ are basis of $M$ and $cl$ has the exchange property then $|A|=|B|$.
I tried by contradiction (as the prove for vector spaces) but I am stuck because I can't find where to use the exchange propery and the assumption of that there are no bijections between $A$ and $B$.
Is there a citation where I can find the proof or do you know of any proof?

@AlexKruckman thank you very much for replying. Yes, I am interested in closure operators on infinite sets. I used the tag [model-theory] because I am taking a model theory course and this is one of the exercises recommended in class. Do you have a counterexample to my statement?, and I would also like to know the proof assuming that $cl$ is not finitary, do you know where I can find it?

I had the pleasure of answering two questions on infinite matroids (closure operators with exchange) today! The other one is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4967221/7062

This isn't true in general.
I'll give a simple version of a counterexample due to Vlastimil Dlab. A more complex version of this construction, which produces a closure operator with bases of sizes equal to an arbitrary family of infinite cardinals, is Theorem 2 in his paper The rôle of the “finite character property” in the theory of dependence from 1965.
Let's say $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is large in the rationals if (a) $A$ contains all but finitely many rational numbers, and (b) if $A$ is missing $n$ rational numbers, then $A$ contains at least $n$ irrational numbers.
Similarly, let's say $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is large in the irrationals if (a) $A$ contains all but finitely many irrational numbers, and (b) if $A$ is missing $n$ irrational numbers, then $A$ contains at least $n$ rational numbers.
Now for $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, define:
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\cl}{cl} \cl(A) = \begin{cases} \mathbb{R}&\text{ if $A$ is large in the rationals or in the irrationals}\\
A& \text{ otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
Then you can check that $\cl$ is a closure operator with exchange and that $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{I}$ are bases of different cardinalities.

To make the theorem true, you need an additional hypothesis. The most common is to assume that $\operatorname{cl}$ is finitary, i.e., if $b\in \operatorname{cl}(A)$, then there is some $A'\subseteq A$ such that $A'$ is finite and $b\in \operatorname{cl}(A')$. Of course, the finitary condition is trivially satisfied if $M$ is finite (so $M$ is a finite matroid). But since you tagged the post [model-theory], I assume you're interested in closure operators on infinite sets.
The closure operators with exchange of interest in model theory (e.g., $\mathrm{acl}$ in a strongly minimal sets) are all finitary. Model theorists usually call finitary closure operators with exchange  "pregometries".
For a proof that any two bases have the same cardinality in the finitary case, you can see Lemma C.1.6 on p. 206 of in Tent and Ziegler's book A Course in Model Theory. It also appears as Lemma 6.1.9(c) in Marker's book Model Theory: An Introduction. Here the proof is given only in the case of acl in a strongly minimal set, but the argument for the general case is exactly the same.
